# remove returned object's property in C#

Tags: c#

I am calling a method to delete an object that contain a specific value. It looks like this:

```
static public void RemovePiece(string BoardId)
{
    LumberPiece board = LocateBoard(BoardId);
    board = null;
}
```

LumberPiece is a class that looks like this:

```
private class LumberPiece
{
    public string boardID;
    ...
}
```

and LocateBoard is a function that returns the correctly identified LumberPiece Object:

```
static private LumberPiece LocateBoard(string BoardId)
{
    if (SawyerArea.lumber.boardID == BoardId)
        return SawyerArea.lumber;
    else if (SpliceArea1.lumber.boardID == BoardId)
        return SpliceArea1.lumber;
    else if (SpliceArea2.lumber.boardID == BoardId)
        return SpliceArea2.lumber;
    else
        throw new Exception("Your LumberID was not found in any activity area. Has it already been removed? or are you handling the integer-String Conversion Correctly");
}
```

The Area variables are instances of this class:

```
private class ActivityArea
{
    public Sensor sensor;
    public ClampSet clampSet;
    public Servo servo;
    public LumberPiece lumber;

    public bool IsCurrentlyFilled()
    {
        if (lumber != null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public ActivityArea(Sensor s, ClampSet cs, Servo srv)
    {
        sensor = s;
        clampSet = cs;
        servo = srv;
    }
```

How can I remove the correctly identified LumberPiece Object?

Comment: You cannot get a pointer to Managed object

Comment: Object variables are always pointers to objects in C#.but they're not called pointers, but references.

Comment: You don't need to. Garbage collector will do that.

Comment: Delete it from what, precisely? In managed languages like C#, you generally delete references to an object, e.g. remove it from a list, and let garbage collection handle the details of when that object is actually destructed.

Comment: Garbage collection is responsible for freeing the memory. All you do is, set the variable to point to null (As you have done).

Comment: @RobvanderVeer Wrong, those are not pointers, they are object references

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, i pressed enter too soon, i was not finished

Comment: @Yogendra - You don't need to set references to null for the associated object to be eligible for collection. Objects can be collected as soon as there are no live references to them.

Comment: @RobvanderVeer Oh I see, but they are not pointers actually

Comment: @Lee...yes, you are right. I wanted to point that GC takes care of everything. We can only set the reference to null (not needed...but thats all we can do )

Comment: @Yogendra setting a local variable to null won't do what the OP presumably *wants* to do, in terms of removing the actual board object from somewhere

Comment: sorry for being unclear see my edits.

Comment: Looks like you actually need a `LocateAreaByBoard` function (which returns the Area which contains the specified board), and then when you find it you can set its `lumber` field to null.

Comment: @Marc Gravell, after the question edit, I see what you are saying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to locate the `ActivityArea` that contains the Lumber object you want to delete.

so for Example you could use this method instead of LocateBoard:

```
static public ActivityArea LocateAreaByBoard(string BoardId)
        {
            if (SawyerArea.lumber.boardID == BoardId)
                return SawyerArea;
            else if (SpliceArea1.lumber.boardID == BoardId)
                return SpliceArea1;
            else if (SpliceArea2.lumber.boardID == BoardId)
                return SpliceArea2;
            else
                throw new Exception("Your LumberID was not found in any activity area. Has it already been removed? or are you handling the integer-String Conversion Correctly");
        }
```

and then you can change your remove code to look like this:

```
ActivityArea area = LocateAreaByBoard(BoardId);
area.lumber = null;
```

And it will give you the desired deletion effects

Answer (score 8):

In garbage collected frameworks like .NET, you don't "delete" the object. You just *stop caring about it*. Once you have no references to it (via any route), the garbage collector will take care of it *in due course*.

This might involve removing the reference from a list, etc - which is usually as simple as:

```
list.Remove(theObject);
```

However, since we can't see where you *stored* the board, we can't tell you how to remove the references to it.

Actually, the work you need to do here is no different to non-GC platforms; you would ***still*** need to remove the pointer from those lists, to avoid a horrible error later when the now-deleted pointer gets accessed.

Comment: Exactly - he needs to go back to the source. He probably wants to make it so that LocateBoard() will not return the lumber when it is deleted. To do that, we need to know where LocateBoard() is looking - a list, a database, a file, etc. It needs to be removed from the source. Or at least marked as "Removed" if he wants to save its history.